# I'm using d3.v3.min.js for showing a data like mindmap structure.I'm having large number of data's so it is very inconvinient to dispaly the data

Tags: angularjs

I have more than 100 data's as a children in a json file,how to show only limited number of data's in chidren node.I have json data with array of children with more than 100data's,i want to show only 10 data's in node and remaining data should be in hide when i expand it should load another data,this should done for every node.Can any one help me out.Here is my code.

And here is my directive:

```
app.directive('mindMap', function () {
    return {
        link: function(scope, element) {


            var eleW = element[0].clientWidth,
                    eleH = element[0].clientHeight;

          var m = [20,40,20,80],
                  w = eleW - m[1] - m[3],
                  h = eleH - m[0] - m[2],
                  i = 0,
                  root;

            var tree = d3.layout.tree().size([h, w]);
            var diagonal = d3.svg.diagonal().projection(function(d) { return [d.y, d.x]; });
            var vis = d3.select(element[0]).append("svg:svg")
                .attr("width", w + m[1] + m[3])
                .attr("height", h + m[0] + m[2])
                .append("svg:g")
                .attr("transform", "translate(" + m[3] + "," + m[0] + ")");
            // Toggle children.
            function toggle(d) {
              if (d.children) {
                d._children = d.children;
                d.children = null;
              } else {
                d.children = d._children;
                d._children = null;
              }
            }

            function toggleAll(d) {
            if (d.children) {
              d.children.forEach(toggleAll);
              toggle(d);
            }
          }


            scope.$watch('json' , function(){
                if(!(scope.json != null)){
                scope.json = {
                    "name" : "root"
                }
              }
              root = scope.json;
              root.x0 = h/2;
            root.y0 = 0;
                update(root);
                scope.root = root;
            });

            function update(source) {
        console.log(source);
              var duration = 500;
              if(!(source != null)){
                return;
              }

              // Compute the new tree layout.
              var nodes = tree.nodes(root).reverse();
              // Normalize for fixed-depth.
              var deepest = 0,
                    generationGutter = w;
              nodes.forEach(function(d){
                if(deepest < d.depth){
                    deepest = d.depth;
                }
              });
              generationGutter = Math.floor(w/(deepest+1));
              nodes.forEach(function(d) { d.y = d.depth * generationGutter; });

              // Update the nodes…

              var node = vis.selectAll("g.node")
                  .data(nodes, function(d) { return d.id || (d.id = ++i); });
            console.log(node);
              // Enter any new nodes at the parent's previous position.
              var nodeEnter = node.enter().append("svg:g")
                  .attr("class", "node")
                  .attr("transform", function(d) { return "translate(" + source.y0 + "," + source.x0 + ")"; });

              //inject content to node
              InjectNodeContent(nodeEnter);

              // Transition nodes to their new position.
              var nodeUpdate = node.transition()
                  .duration(duration)
                  .attr("transform", function(d) { return "translate(" + d.y + "," + d.x + ")"; });

              nodeUpdate.select("circle")
                  .attr("r", 4.5)
                  .style("fill", function(d) { return d._children ? "lightsteelblue" : "#fff"; });

              nodeUpdate.select("text")
                    .text(function(d) { return d.name; })
                  .style("fill-opacity", 1);

              // Transition exiting nodes to the parent's new position.
              var nodeExit = node.exit().transition()
                  .duration(duration)
                  .attr("transform", function(d) { return "translate(" + source.y + "," + source.x + ")"; })
                  .remove();

              nodeExit.select("circle")
                  .attr("r", 1e-6);

              nodeExit.select("text")
                  .style("fill-opacity", 1e-6);

              // Update the links…
              var link = vis.selectAll("path.link")
                  .data(tree.links(nodes), function(d) { return d.target.id; });

              // Enter any new links at the parent's previous position.
              link.enter().insert("svg:path", "g")
                  .attr("class", "link")
                  .attr("d", function(d) {
                    var o = {x: source.x0, y: source.y0};
                    return diagonal({source: o, target: o});
                  })
                .transition()
                  .duration(duration)
                  .attr("d", diagonal);

              // Transition links to their new position.
              link.transition()
                  .duration(duration)
                  .attr("d", diagonal);

              // Transition exiting nodes to the parent's new position.
              link.exit().transition()
                  .duration(duration)
                  .attr("d", function(d) {
                    var o = {x: source.x, y: source.y};
                    return diagonal({source: o, target: o});
                  })
                  .remove();

              // Stash the old positions for transition.
              nodes.forEach(function(d) {
                d.x0 = d.x;
                d.y0 = d.y;
              });
            }


            function InjectNodeContent (nodeEnter) {
                nodeEnter.append("svg:circle")
                  .attr("r", 1e-6)
                  .style("fill", function(d) { return d._children ? "lightsteelblue" : "#fff"; })
                  .classed("toggleCircle" , true)
                  .on("click", function(d) {
                        toggle(d);
                        update(d);
                  });

              nodeEnter.append("svg:text")
                  .attr("x", function(d) { return d.children || d._children ? -10 : 10; })
                  .attr("dy", ".35em")
                  .attr("text-anchor", function(d) { return d.children || d._children ? "end" : "start"; })
                  .text(function(d) { return d.name; })
                  .style("fill-opacity", 1e-6);

            }
        }
    }
});
```

My sample JSON data:

```
{
  "name": "Parent",
  "children": [
  {
    "name": "child1",
    "children": [

      {"name": "subchild1"},
      {"name": "subchild2"}
    ]
  },
  {
    "name": "child2",
    "children": [
      {"name": "subchild3"},
      {"name": "subchild4"}
    ]
  },
  {"name": "subchild5"},
  {"name": "subchild6"},
  {"name": "subchild7"},
  {"name": "subchild8"},
  {"name": "subchild9"}
  ]
}
```

Comment: Could we have a sample of your data please ?

Comment: Sample json data updated there will be lot number of data's in the children array.@PierreCapo